# How to make HTTP request to call a report

Tags: angular6

On .Net side there is System.net and WebClient to make http request; In Angular 6 what's the way to

1. Add user name password to the header of HTTP request.
2. Make http request to call a Jasper/SSRS report via url
3. Display the response in a new browser window.

Thanks